# Is there any way to convert Wikitext to Markdown in python?

Tags: python, mediawiki, markdown, text-processing

Is there a python library which takes wikitext (as used in mediawiki) input and converts it to markdown?

Comment: Can you even do that? I never really used wikitext, but isn't it orders of magnitude more powerful/fine-grained than markdown?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a perfect conversion, as long as it preserves the general structure.

Comment: to convert a full wiki to markdown, see [mediawiki-to-markdown](https://github.com/philipashlock/mediawiki-to-markdown) or [mediawiki-to-gfm](https://github.com/outofcontrol/mediawiki-to-gfm) or [mediawiki_to_git_md](https://github.com/peterjc/mediawiki_to_git_md) or [alsa](https://github.com/markc/alsa)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since is something that I need, I packaged both together:

http://bitbucket.org/wikier/mw2md

So now it's easier to perform both tasks.

Comment: Here's what I see when I try to access that link: https://i.imgur.com/0jY04pX.png

Comment: link is dead, "Repository not found". web archive returns empty page. there are some [mw2md on github](https://github.com/search?q=mw2md&ref=opensearch&type=repositories)

Answer (score 6):

You can go from [wikitext to html](http://wiki.sheep.art.pl/Wiki%20Creole%20Parser%20in%20Python) and then go from [html to markdown](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/). Not exactly straight forward, but i know no alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for WikiCreole. It doesn't seem to work for MediaWiki markup. I have not yet found a reliable standalone Mediawiki to HTML-or-whatever converter.

Comment: the first hyperlink isn't useful any longer

Answer (score 4):

Not sure it does what you want, but you might want to check out [Pyandoc](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pyandoc): a Python wrapper for [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for this. Try [online converter](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandoc with following syntax to convert from mediwiki to markdown.

```
 pandoc -f mediawiki -t markdown wiki.txt
```

this will output on console but if you want to save it in a file then change as below.

```
pandoc --from mediawiki --to markdown wiki.txt  -o youwant.md
```

Comment: pandoc is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a still working solution: a Python Library that uses Pandoc.

[pypandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/)