# Calling pandoc from python using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, pandoc

I am having problems calling pandoc from python using `subprocess.Popen`. It all works in the console. Here is the code.

```
# Test markdown file
here is just a simple markdown file.
```

Now my python code using that `filename` is the full path my markdown file:

```
import subprocess
fileout = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".pdf"
args = ['pandoc', filename, '-o', fileout]
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

I also tried various ways to capture an error but that didn't work. In the console, however, everything is running fine:

```
pandoc '[filename]' -o '[fileout]'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work just fine, but you may want to wait for it to finish using [`subprocess.check_call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) rather than [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) directly:

```
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

This also makes sure that it completed *successfully*. If the status code isn't 0, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't answer your question (and you may specifically want/need to call pandoc using subprocess.Popen) but there is a Python wrapper for Pandoc called [Pyandoc](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pyandoc): see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980904/is-there-any-way-to-convert-wikitext-to-markdown-in-python/13707263#13707263).

Comment: That as of 2023 is unmaintained and is a small wrapper around a subprocesss call.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really like using `PIPE`, it's more complicated, and the Python docs on `subprocess` recommend not to use it if not necessary (see [section 17.1.1](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)).

This works for me (taken from [Markx](https://github.com/yoavram/markx/blob/master/server.py)).

Filename is the name of the markdown file without `.md`, and extension in the desired output (`.pdf`, `.docx`):

```
def pandoc(filename, extension):
    # TODO manage pandoc errors, for example exit status 43 when citations include Snigowski et al. 2000
    options = ['pandoc', filename + '.md', '-o', filename + extension]
    options += ['--ascii', '-s', '--toc'] # some extra options
    options += ['--variable=geometry:' + 'a4paper'] # to override the default letter size
    print(options)  # for debugging
    return subprocess.check_call(options)
```

If there was a problem an exception in raised. If you want to get the status code instead of an exception, I think you should replace `check_call` with `call`, but see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

If you want to use citations see my original implementation from the [Markx](https://github.com/yoavram/markx/blob/master/server.py) project with the `bibliography` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the stdout and stderr resulting from the Popen call, you'll need to use PIPE in conjunction with communicate().

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

fileout = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".pdf"
args = ['pandoc', filename, '-o', fileout]
stdout, stderr = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```